# Django admin utilizar os atributos da request

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Django e utilizei os dados da request no `form` para validar alguns campos.

Por exemplo, se o usuário que estiver alterando o `form` for do grupo "Administrador", ao mudar a senha do usuário ele não precisa informar a senha antiga.

Porém, quando vou salvar uma alteração de usuário no admin, ele dá um erro justamente por não estar recebendo o atributo `request`.

Abaixo seguem os códigos do `form` em que utilizei o clean method para determinados atributos. Alguém sabe como receber os atributos da `request` no admin?

Método init alterado para receber a `request`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    f = self.fields.get('user_permissions', None)
    if f is not None:
        f.queryset = f.queryset.select_related('content_type')
```

Método clean para o campo `groups`:

```
def clean_groups(self):
    if self.request.user.groups.all() or self.request.user.is_staff:
        if self.request.user.groups.filter(name="Administrador") or self.request.user.is_staff:
            return self.cleaned_data['groups']
        else:
            if list(self.cleaned_data['groups']) == list(self.request.user.groups.all()):
                return self.cleaned_data['groups']
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['non_administrator'],
                    code='non_administrator',
                    )
    elif not self.request.user.groups.all() and self.cleaned_data['groups']:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['non_administrator'],
            code='non_administrator',
            )
    elif not self.request.user.groups.all() and not self.cleaned_data['groups']:
        return self.cleaned_data['groups']
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso esteja utilizando admin utilize o [get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) para aplicar o formulário de acordo com a permissão do usuário logado. Para todas as verificações de permissões de usuário é interessante que fique por lá. Mas caso queira algo diferente tente submeter o request na instância do formulário, algo como:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        kwargs['form'] = UserChangeForm
    return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

ou

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    kwargs['form'] = UserChangeForm(request=request)
    return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```